# jssor thumb custom class

Tags: jquery, slider, jssor

I'm trying desperately to change the classname of the thumbnails in my jssor slider.

I have following code:

```
<div><a u="image" href="[+ic.property.Href+]" title="[+ic.resources.exclusive+]    [+ic.property.type+] [+ic.resources.in+] [+ic.property.area+]">
<img u="image" src="[+ic.GetImageUrl+]" />
<img u="thumb" src="[+ic.GetImageUrl+]" class="[+ic.property.imgClass+]" />
<div class="tnt_caption_container">
<div class="tnt_caption_content">
[+ic.propertyTitle+] · [+ic.property.price+]
</div>
</a></div>
</div>
```

The variable [+ic.property.imgClass+] can be empty or not...
What I want to archive is to overlap some images with another .png (new, exclusive etc) as long as they fulfill certain conditions.

If I add a div element before the , it will simply not be there when the page is loaded. And all  have class=""... Even if I remove my code, the class name still remains empty. So I assume that js is emptying the classnames when it's creating the slider, but I couldnt figure out where this happens.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

use following format to define thumbnail with custom class,

```
<div u="thumb">
    <img src="[+ic.GetImageUrl+]" class="[+ic.property.imgClass+]" />
</div>
```

Comment: It didnt work :( I have added more details about what I tried, hoping to help you helping me!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div u="thumb">
    <img src="[+ic.GetImageUrl+]" class="myClass" />
</div>
```

Please note that your class applys to the element <img src="[+ic.GetImageUrl+]" class="myClass" /> only

btw, please check your code 'class="[+ic.property.imgClass+]"', it generates 'class=""'.

Comment: Do you mean that the variable [+ic.property.imgClass+] is empty? I can tell that is it not. As I said, even if I write class="test", class will later be empty. Anyhow, how can I achieve to overlay all thumbnails with a png? That would be enough.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work? You can see the slider in action here: http://satorreproperties.com/